# React onClick preinitialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

This is my React.component code. OnClick event executed on page initialization and i cant fix this, i tried 2 pull onClick over the maping, but this has no sense:

```
handleClick (id){
        alert(id);
    }

    render() {
        var tmp = this.handleClick;
        return(
            <div className="thirteen wide column">
                <div className="rrc-title">Магазины, нарушающие РРЦ</div>
                <div className="custom-hr"></div>
                <div className="ui grid">
                    {
                        jsonResult.data.map(function(el){
                            return (

                                <div className="three wide column">
                                    <div className="store-item-bad" onClick={tmp(el.siteId)}>
                                        <div className="siteName">{el.siteName}</div>
                                        {
                                            el.values.map(function(element){
                                                var processWidth ={
                                                    background : element.color,
                                                    width: element.percent+'%'
                                                }
                                                return(
                                                    <div className="BarItem">
                                                        <div className="progressBar">
                                                            <div className="ui tiny progress">
                                                                <div className="bar" style={processWidth}></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="progressCounter">{element.count}</div>
                                                    </div>)

                                            })
                                        }

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="rrc-title">Магазины, соблюдающие РРЦ</div>
                <div className="custom-hr"></div>
                <div className="ui grid">
                    {
                        jsonResult.data.map(function(el){
                            return (
                                <div className="three wide column">
                                    <div className="store-item-ok">
                                        <div className="siteName">{el.siteName}</div>
                                        {
                                            el.values.map(function(element){
                                                var processWidth ={
                                                    background : element.color,
                                                    width: element.percent+'%'
                                                }
                                                return(
                                                <div className="BarItem">
                                                    <div className="progressBar BarFloatingLeft">
                                                        <div className="ui tiny progress">
                                                            <div className="bar" style={processWidth}></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="progressCounter">{element.count}</div>
                                                </div>)

                                            })
                                        }

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    }

                </div></div>
        );
    }
```

It's easy thing, but i can't focus right now, so i need ur help guys:)

Comment: are you using class, or React.createClass?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,el.siteId)} or
onClick={tmp.bind(this,el.siteId)}
```

And add arrow func in map:

```
map(e=>{})
```

Comment: we cant use this in map

Comment: but thx u solve this 

this is upd solution 4 my code //onClick={tmp.bind(this,el.siteId)}